# Android Update app on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I have some questions related to updating an android app on Google Play, that I seem to find the answer nowhere. I updated an app, and after aprox an hour, I noticed a problem with that new apk, so I had to create a newer update. I read on Google Docs that an update would take up to 24 hours to be surelly released to users, so if I will update it again, would that be a problem? Will the users see only the last update? Can I deactivate an update and let only the last one to be released? I appreciate any answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you notice a problem in just released version, you can deactivate it and activate the previous version (you can do that in advanced mode). Some users may get the new release in the meantime though.

You can later release a new version and users will then see this new version as the upgrade.

Comment: Nice one, I wasn't sure about the deactivate / activate options, but you seem to know better. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

just sign your new apk with old keystore and got o console old app console and in you may/maynot  unpublish your old version.just add new apk to production and it will update in 2-3 hours.